# RMagick is unable to open file that I know exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, rmagick

I am running this code in my model on an after_update call:

```
require 'rmagick'
file = photo.url(:thumb) #created by paperclip
img = Magick::Image.read(file).first
```

and I get unable to open file `/assets/contacts/1/thumb/image.png' though that file is there and is used throughout the rest of the app, so I don't suspect permissions as an issue. Rails is looking at my assets directory for everything else, and I can access the image via direct URL on my local box, so I know it exists. I do have ImageMagick installed via homebrew, and I ran "identify -list format" and the formats seem to be installed too. I have added it to the gemfile and run bundle install as well. What other things could I try to troubleshoot this?

How do I know what directory RMagick thinks is root, or is there some other reason why I can't read the file? I have read all I can find on Google, forums, Stack, IRC, and no one seems to have an answer.

Comment: Added that, getting the same exact url in console.

Comment: can you try to do this same think with a hard coded url?

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip gem stores uploaded images in public folder. So, if your image path inside public folder is: 
    contacts --> 1  --> thumb --> image.png

Than, you should use path **'/contacts/1/thumb/image.png'** . Because, if there is no forward slash in URL than rails will by default search inside the **assets** folder for images.